# two forms with required inputs

Tags: html

I have a page with two forms. They do different things. They both have inputs with `required="required"`.

My problem is that if I try to click on a required input of the second form, the browser forces me to fill the fields of the first one.

Is this behavior correct? I mean is the browser expected to work like this because html5 supposes to have just one form with required inputs per page? Or am I doing something wrong with the code?

Comment: Something is wrong. A required form field validation should occur on submission, not on blur. Make sure there's no weird JavaScript involved.

Comment: have you given different names to each input field? could you please show the html for your forms?

Comment: ARGH! I've been spending a lot of time checking the ids of the inputs, then I discovered that the label tags where wrong....

Answer (score 0):

Is there any nested form in your page?. first form tag not work in nested forms like below. in that case use empty form tag to avoid error. and also do not write class with form tag starting like form.filed{}

```
<form>
main form
<form> </form>
<form> form1 </form>
<form> form2 </form>

</form>
```